# Define the variable of a function call indirectly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two files `file1.py` and `file2.py`.

I execute a function from `file2.py` which executes a function from `file1.py`.

```py
# tree/file1.py

def transfer(.., token="Y"):
    ...
```

```py
# tree/file2.py

from .file1 import transfer

def secure(..):
    ...
    transfer(..) #the `token` argument does not need to be called here.

def main(..):
    ...
    secure(..)
```

The `transfer` function from `file1.py` is used in several other files in the tree.

Could I, from outside the tree, set the token variable for the `transfer` function in my `file1.py`? Which would be applied for all these executions.

```py
# outside the tree folder
from tree.file2 import main
token = ?
# choose the token variable and apply it to the transfer function 
main(..)
```

This would save me from overloading the code and having to put a token argument to all the functions. I want the user to be able to choose his token. Avoid this:

```py
from tree.file2 import main
token = "X"
# choose the token variable and apply it to the transfer function 
main(.., token=token)
# and be forced to put the token argument to all functions..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be that `file1.py` should be left alone because if you ever want to use a different `token` the function is already defined to take a token: `def transfer(.., token):`

One possibility is to make an intermediary:

```py
# file1a.py
from .file1 import transfer as tr

def transfer(...):
    token = "X"
    tr(..., token)
```

Now all other modules need to have this: `from .file1a import transfer`

(if you have hundreds of files and you don't want to change the import, you could swap the contents of `file1.py` for `file1a.py`)

You can also effectively mock out the actual function and make all functions automatically call your own function which supplies the required token:

```py
from tree.file1 import transfer as tr

def transfer(...):
    token = "X"        # this function substitutes a different token
    return tr(..., token)  # call to the real function

import tree.file1 as file1
file1.transfer = transfer   # this sets up the mock from here

from tree.file2 import main

main(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, and what would it look like to call the main function and choose the token from a file outside the tree directory (as in my end example)? If I did that I would be forced to define the other arguments to the transfer() function ?.. Ideally I don't want to have token argument defined in the other functions. **I edited the question**.

Comment: This works very well, thank you. Did you recommend a different title for the post more directly related to the topic? I wasn't sure how to phrase it.

Answer (score 0):

What follows is a whirlwind tour of maintaining mutable state between function calls, of which the default argument is but one example.

---

If you want a "configurable" default value, use a sentinel to detect when no argument is passed, then assign a module global to the parameter.

```
transfer_default = "Y"

def transfer(.., token=None):
    if token is None:
        token = transfer_token
    ...
```

---

You can *technically* alter a preset default value (by replacing *all* the defaults at once, since they are stored in an immutable tuple):

```
# Assuming token is the first/only parameter with a default
transfer.__defaults__ = ("N",)
```

but I don't recommend it.

---

You can also use a closure to allow the caller to create their own version of `transfer` with whatever default they want:

```
def make_transfer(default):
    def _(..., token=default):
        ...
    return _

transfer1 = make_transfer("Y")
transfer2 = make_transfer("N")
```

While you could always use `make_transfer("Y")(...)` on demand, instead of reusing `transfer1(...)`, keep in mind that `make_transfer` has to define a new function every time it is called.

---

Using a closure leads to the dual of a closure, a class.

```
class Transferrer:
    def __init__(self, token="Y"):
        self.token = token

    def transfer(self):
        ...

Transferrer().transfer()  # with Y
Transferrer("N").transfer()  # with N
```

As with closures, you probably want to reuse the same `Transferrer` object multiple times, rather than always creating a new one each time you want to call its `transfer` method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, `.__defaults__ =` particularly interested me, why don't you recommend it here? And if possible, could you give an example of its use in a file outside the tree directory (as in my final example).

Comment: It's an implentation detail, not part of the public interface of a `function` object.